# How to think to get all content inline (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm a really new at this but I don't manage to ge the menu bar to get in line with the rest of the content on the page. Can someone just explain how to think to get everything in line and so everything scale nicely?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="all">

<ul id="menu1">
    <li><img src="Pic/Homemini.png"></li>
    <li><img src="Pic/MeMINI.png"></li>
    <li><img src="Pic/portfolioMINI.png"></li>
    <li><img src="Pic/contactMINI.png"></li>
</ul>

<ul id="menu2">
    <li><img src="Pic/Home.png"></li>
    <li><img src="Pic/Me.png"></li>
    <li><img src="Pic/portfolio.png"></li>
    <li><img src="Pic/Contact.png"></li>
</ul>


<div id="box1MINI"><img src="Pic/box1MINI.png"></div>
<div id="main"><img src="Pic/main.png"></div>

<footer>
    <p>DID YOU KNOW?</p>
    <p>alsdjaljsdkasjd askldjalksdj <br> asdlkjaslkd asldkjasldj asldk <br> alsdkjalksdj lakdj</p>
</footer>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
                                            /* ALL CONTENT */
* {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#all{
margin: auto;   
}
                                    /* END ALL CONTENT */
                                        /* HEADER */
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}

#menu2{
    display: none;

}

#box1MINI{
    max-width: 80%;
    min-width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
                                        /* END HEADER*/
                                        /* MAIN SPACE */
#main{
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
}

                                        /* END MAIN SPACE */
                                        /* FOOTER*/
footer{
    background-color: darkgreen;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

                                        /* END FOOTER*/
```

Comment: Question not really clear to me..

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your code? I created "http://jsfiddle.net/r74wf9cc/1/" using your posted code but looks like some mess... It would be more helpful if you can create one using "http://jsfiddle.net/" and share

Comment: I don't manage to get everything on the page centered. The menu bar in top is more to the left. @KheemaPandey

Comment: @UID: it helps to add `border:1px solid #000` to the `*` selector, everything is more clear.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fswempe/ You won't se the pictures but you se when you scale that the menubar i more to the left @UID

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow no it don't help. Just create a border. Not solwe my problem with the menubar.

Comment: I only meant it helps to visualize the problem for anyone trying to solve it.

Comment: @Danju: I have updated my answer with working code!!! Please check if this is what you are looking for! Meanwhile I'll be adding the explanation also for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you were getting because you gave **"60%" width to "#box1MINI"** and **"80%" to "#main and footer"**. And **no width to "Menus"**

Whereas you should give width to the "Outermost" container which is "**#all**" in your case. and set that to center by "`margin: 0 auto;`" property. And keep everything else inside the "#all" container.

I have updated your code and made some modifications as per good practice.

Please find the Updated code below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="all">
    <ul id="menu1">
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/Homemini.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/MeMINI.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/portfolioMINI.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/contactMINI.png">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="menu2">
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/Home.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/Me.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/portfolio.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="Pic/Contact.png">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="box1MINI">
        <img src="Pic/box1MINI.png">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <img src="Pic/main.png">
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>DID YOU KNOW?</p>
        <p>
            alsdjaljsdkasjd askldjalksdj
        <br>
            asdlkjaslkd asldkjasldj asldk
        <br>
            alsdkjalksdj lakdj
        </p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #all {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
    }
    /* END ALL CONTENT */
    /* HEADER */
    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

        ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 24.6%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    #menu2 {
        display: block;
    }

    #box1MINI {
        min-width: 60%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    /* END HEADER*/
    /* MAIN SPACE */
    #main {
        margin: auto;
    }
    /* END MAIN SPACE */
    /* FOOTER*/
    footer {
        background-color: darkgreen;
        padding: 1px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    /* END FOOTER*/
```

### Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/96ft87ev/1/

Hope this will help!

Let me know if you were looking for something else!

Comment: Thank you so much @UID! I have one question about the body{ height: 100%;}. Is it necessary and why it's react differently when I put the line under * ?

Comment: Question 1 > Its not necessary to put "height: 100%;" under Body and HTML. But in-case you want to give height in "%" to some DIV, the rule says that its parent tag should have some height defined so we give "height:100%" to HTML and BODY tag.

Comment: Question 2 > the layout works weird when you put "height: 100%;" under "*", because, "*" is a shortcut of all the tags. so that means you are giving height to all the tags in your layout and that is why the layout stretches.

Answer (score 0):

Add this selector:

```
#menu1 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Since you've set the `li` elements to be displayed as inline, they conform to text-alignment rules.

Edit: After this, the nav bar was still slightly off-center. This is due to a couple reasons. First of all, parts of your HTML are invalid, resulting in tags not being nested properly. Your `link`, `img`, and `br` tags all need to be self-closing. That just means you need to add a `/` (slash) before the `>` symbol on the tag.
After you've fixed that, simply remove the padding that is added to the `li` elements by adding `padding:0` to the `#menu1` selector.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/as0cz5s0/) is an example (I've added borders, but you can remove them).

Comment: When I add that sector the menubar now is more to the right and not in same line as the rest. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/5fswempe/1/

Answer (score 0):

When using percentages, it uses the parent to calculate. You want each li to be 20% of the page, not 20% of the parent (ul). Set the width for menu1 as 80%, then each li is 25% of that. Give the ul auto margins and it will line up with content.

```
#menu1{
    margin: auto;
    width:80%; //same as content
    padding: 0px;
}
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    width: calc(25% -4px); //each image is 25% of the parent, parent is 80% of page
    box-sizing: border-box; //includes border and padding in box size

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrbq1ury/)